# Getting a date from a string containing a date with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Basically, I have a string like this:

> text text text text text 1/12/2012 text text text text

I need to somehow get that date out of the string. I'm terrible with regular expressions, and I was wondering if there's an easy way to get it with jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this, just use a regular expression, eg.

```
/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/.exec('text text 1/12/2012 text text')
```

Note, that this only extracts strings that look like a date and they may be invalid.

Comment: The exec function returns an array, so you will need to use `tdate[0]` to get the matched part of the string.